# Symmetric Encryption in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I use Symmetric Encryption on a database and then back it up and then restore it to another SQL Server and use the same keys I can't decrypt the data.

Is there a way around this?

Using SQL Server 2008

Code:

```
GO 
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD' 
GO 

CREATE CERTIFICATE PasswordFieldCertificate WITH SUBJECT = 'Password Fields';
GO 
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordFieldSymmetricKey WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordFieldCertificate; 
GO
```

Comment: What method are you using to perform the encryption? Can you show your code (minus the key)? This can't be answered without more information.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Restore a database backup to a different machine then where it was backed up:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password'
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
CLOSE MASTER KEY
```

Note: If you don't do this, then you will not be able to decrypt the data.